# using mongodb with filestack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, image-uploading, image-upload

Can anyone please give me some pointers on using MongoDb and Filestack together? After I upload a photo to filestack; how do I save the response filestack sends to mongodb: For example the url of a photo that I have uploaded to filestack, so that it's accessible on my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the response from your filestack .pick() as an ajax post to your MongoDB.